# Problems with citing in bibgerm

Tags: citing

[image]

Ive tried to cite this in bibgerm but it just spits out a |?| instead of a citation. Works fine in biblatex but id have to change all settings What am i missing?

{And why do deleted references still show up in the suggestions when writing \cite ?}

Comment: without a small but complete example one can't test, but the braces around the key look odd.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh those dont belong there, didnt work without them either tho

Comment: @MarcelDavis you have not provided a MWE as asked by Ulrike, so nobody can try your code to see what is going wrong. And better put raw text instead of a screenshot, we can't copy/paste screenshots.